# Гарантировано ли корректное выполнение блока кода после "delete this"?

Tags: c++

Пусть у меня есть класс:

```
class A
{
public:
int foo()
{
//some code before

delete this;

//some code after
return something;
}
};
```

Работаю я с ним, естественно, так:

```
A* a = new A();
auto result = a->foo();
```

Вопрос: гарантировано ли корректное выполнение блока кода после "delete this" с учетом того, что я не буду обращаться к переменным-членам класса после этой строчки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#delete-this

Получается, что можно если:

- объект гарантированно аллоцирован на куче
- после вызова метода foo других методов для данного объекта вызвано не будет
- внутри метода foo после строчки "delete this" ни один метод или инструкция не трогает this прямо или косвенно
- внутри метода foo после строчки "delete this" ни один метод или инструкция не изменяют переменные-члены класса (включая и код деструктора)

Answer (score 1):

Вызов функции-члена похож на вызов обычной функции, только для неё дополнительно происходит неявная инициализация `this` указателем на тот объект, для которого эта функция вызвана. Поэтому, если Вы удаляете `this`, но после этого к нему не обращаетесь, то и проблем у Вас быть не может.

Answer (score 0):

Если нет обращение к членам прямо или косвенно, вызовов виртуальных функций, то проблемы быть не должно. Здесь надо понимать, что `delete this;` вызывает деструктор и производит освобождение памяти в куче. Т.е. надо гарантировать, что объект создан через `new`. В общем случае эквивалентный код (без `foo`) мог бы выглядеть так:

```
A* a = new A();
//some code before
delete a;
//some code after
auto result = something
```

И здесь всё поведение (когда можно к кому обращаться) становится, на мой взгляд, очевидным.

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к ответу @alexolut - крайне рекомендовал бы сделать деструктор такого класса `private` - это предупредит создание автоматических переменных такого класса, оставляя возможность создавать их динамически.

И небольшое IMHO - мне кажется, лучше воспользоваться интеллектуальным указателем, чем прятать удаление объекта в вызываемый метод - слишком легко потом запутаться, что к чему, какой метод удаляет объект, а какой - нет, и нарваться на неприятности...

Comment: я не спорю с тем, что приведенный выше код лучше не писать, ибо он запутывает. Вопрос создания объекта класса в куче так же оставлен за скобками. Здесь сугубо научный интерес, если можно так выразиться))